# I’m trying to sum the return value of 2 threads together but it return -1 saying error

Tags: arrays, c, pthreads

I’m trying to make a program which sums the numbers in an array, the first half of the array by the first thread and the second half by the second thread and then printing out to the terminal the sum of both.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int vettore[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

void *p1 (void *arg){
    int *primoritorno = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    for(int i=0; i<=4 ; i++){
        *primoritorno+=vettore[i];
        }
    printf("Il valore della prima metà e' %d \n", *primoritorno);
    return primoritorno;

}

void *p2 (void *arg){
    int *secondoritorno = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    for(int i=0; i<=4 ; i++){
        *secondoritorno+=vettore[i+5];
        }
    printf("Il valore della seconda metà e' %d \n", *secondoritorno);
    return secondoritorno;

}

int main (int argc, char **argv){
    int risultato = 0;
    void *primameta;
    void *secondameta;

    pthread_t primo;
    pthread_t secondo;

    pthread_create (&primo, NULL, p1, NULL);
    pthread_join (primo, &primameta);
    
    pthread_create (&secondo, NULL, p2, NULL);
    pthread_join (secondo, &secondameta);

    //risultato=primameta+secondameta;
    printf("Il risultato e' %d \n", risultato);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `malloc` function allocates memory, but it doesn't initialize the memory in any way. The memory will have *indeterminate* data (look at it as garbage).

Comment: You could fix it by replacing malloc with calloc. Or just `*primoritorno = 0;` after the malloc call. Voting to close as simple typo.

Comment: Also remember that `primameta` and `secondameta` are *pointers* to integers. So you can't use their direct values in your addition, you must dereference the pointers.

Comment: Okay thank you for your input, could you clarify with what you mean that I must dereference the pointers?

Comment: In the comment, you do `primameta+secondameta`. That adds two pointers which makes no sense.

Comment: Okay thanks, i will try to figure out how to fix it since I’m not very experienced with coding in general.

Comment: Pointer arithmetic or de-referencing on void pointers will yield compiler errors. You should cast the pointers to `int*` before de-referencing.

Comment: Do I have to cast the pointers to int* in the function or in the main? Because I just tried and it’s saying that primoritorno and secondoritorno aren’t declared in this scope

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not summing the results, "risultato=primameta+secondameta;" is commented out.
Regarding your question "Do I have to cast the pointers to int* in the function or in the main? Because I just tried and it’s saying that primoritorno and secondoritorno aren’t declared in this scope"
I would declare primameta and secondameta as int pointers; So you could just dereference it when summing the results. As consequence, you would have to cast it to double void pointer when joining the thread. Like this:

```
int *primameta;
int *secondameta;

pthread_t primo;
pthread_t secondo;

pthread_create (&primo, NULL, p1, NULL);
pthread_join (primo, (void**)&primameta);

pthread_create (&secondo, NULL, p2, NULL);
pthread_join (secondo, (void**)&secondameta);

risultato = *primameta + *secondameta;
printf("Il risultato e' %d \n", risultato);
```

Also, please, note that vettore is declared with length 10, but only 9 integers were assigned to it and in the for loop of p2, the iteration goes until i<=4, for i = 4, it is trying to add vettore at its 9th position which is not initialized. You could declare vettore[9] = {...} and loop until i<4;

Comment: You might be interested in watching this tutorial, it is basically the same what you are trying to achieve: Practical example for using threads #1 (Summing numbers from an array)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Adtrk3PREQI&list=PLfqABt5AS4FmuQf70psXrsMLEDQXNkLq2&index=8